# scrollTop only works in Firefox

Tags: jquery, webkit, background-image, parallax, scrolltop

Essentially, I am trying to achieve a parallax effect by animating the background position of a div based on the distance scrolled. This works perfectly in Firefox but it looks like to webkit-based browsers aren't working. That is to say all other browsers are not returning a value for the scrollTop() of the body. I have tried 'document', 'window', 'body,html' etc but nothing else works.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7WVc4/

Here's the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').scroll(function(){
        var scrolled = $('body').scrollTop();
        scrolled*=-0.4;
        $('#container').css('background-position','0px ' + scrolled + 'px');  
    });
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id='container'></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#container {
    background-image:url('http://subtlepatterns.com/patterns/food.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width:80%;
    margin:auto;
    height:1000px;
}
```

Comment: @Ashley Medway Thanks for the answer- it's working in Chrome now but not Firefox, maybe some conditional browser stuff could sort it out?

Comment: @Drew Baker Works fine in JSFiddle, but that's not working in Chrome, Safari or Firefox in the wild I'm afraid.

Comment: please add comments to my answer directly. I updated it with a link showing that it does work in the wild.

Comment: Did you solve this? Was my answer correct?

Comment: Fin, are you still working on this? Can you accept an answer.

Comment: @DrewBaker I am still working on this- sorry for the total lack of engagement. I will be away for a week or so but I will get my head down when I get back.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scrolled = $(document).scrollTop();
        scrolled*=-0.4;
        $('#container').css('background-position','0px ' + scrolled + 'px');  
    });
});
```

Here is an example, showing it work it it's most basic form:
http://labs.funkhausdesign.com/examples/parallax/basic/index.html

It is working in Chrome 32+, Firefox 26+ and Safari 7+.

Comment: Sorry about that. Thanks for the link. It's working in Safari and Chrome but I'm having no luck with Firefox. Any ideas?

Comment: OK, tweaked the scrollTop selector to document, and now it works across all 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now your site does indeed work, but the site I'm working on still doesn't- shall I share a link?

Comment: Yeah share the link if you can.

Comment: Hi, here's the link: http://finmoorhouse.com/experiments/. It looks like the css file, 'foundations.css' is the culprit, because if you remove that the div on the right begins to work and the div on the left ceases to do so, although I can't figure out why. As of now, the div on the left only works in Firefox. Do you have any suggestions as to why this is the case?

Comment: Your HTML and CSS doesn't validate. That will be what is causing it. http://validator.w3.org and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7WVc4/11/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("scroll", function () {
        var scrolled = $('body').scrollTop();
        scrolled*=-0.4;
        $('#container').css('background-position','0px ' + scrolled + 'px');  
    });
});
```

Comment: Does $(document).on('scroll') fire anytime anything is scrolled in the document, like an overflow on a DIV for example?

Comment: possibly. I'll check this.